# Edit file based on existence of a string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have an input file, say, `file1`, which appears as follows:

```
WRITE=2
START=1
SMEAR=0
MIN=6
MAX=100
```

My problem is to search for the string `SMEAR` and if the string exists replace the entire line with `SMEAR=-5`. However, if the `SMEAR` does not exist, then I need to insert a new line `SMEAR=-5`. Ultimately the line `SMEAR=-5` should appear only once.
I can replace the string using sed:

```
 sed -i '/SMEAR/c\SMEAR=-5' file1
```

Or I can insert the string as a new line

```
 sed -i '10i SMEAR=-5' file1
```

But how can I combine them based on the existence of the string in the file?

**EDIT:**
Also it would be helpful if I can pass the value of `SMEAR` as a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the sequence of the lines doesn't matter for your use case.  Given that, I would use `ex` and simply:

1. Remove all instances of `SMEAR`;
2. Insert the line you want.

You can do this like so:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/SMEAR/d' '$a' 'SMEAR=-5' . x | ex file.txt
```

The first command is to `g`lobally `d`elete all lines which match the regex `/SMEAR/`.

The next command is to `a`ppend after the last line (`$`) the line `SMEAR=-5`.  The `.` ends the text to be appended.

The `x` command saves changes and exits.

Each command is terminated by a newline by using `printf '%s\n'` to send them to `ex`.

---

Also see [this very similar solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6248/4676) which I wrote a while back on the vi/Vim stack exchange.

---

To test the changes by printing the changed file to the command line without saving the changes, replace the `x` with the two commands `%p 'q!'` like so:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/SMEAR/d' '$a' 'SMEAR=-5' . %p 'q!' | ex file.txt
```

`%` means "entire buffer," which is what gets `p`rinted.

`q!` means "quit, discarding changes."

To save the changes into a *new* file, replace the `%p` with `w newfile.txt` like so:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/SMEAR/d' '$a' 'SMEAR=-5' . 'w newfile.txt' 'q!' | ex file.txt
```

This `w`rites the modified buffer into `newfile.txt`.

Alternatively you could do this at the start, to make a backup, and then save the changed file contents to the original location, `file.txt`, like so:

```
printf '%s\n' 'w file.txt.bak' 'g/SMEAR/d' '$a' 'SMEAR=-5' . x | ex file.txt
```

---

**Edit:** Actually you don't need to use `q!`; simply omitting the `x` is enough to avoid saving changes.  When `ex` gets an EOF on trying to read further input, it will exit, and will not save changes.

Comment: Is there a way to backup the original file. Something equivalent to `-i.bkp` in `sed`

Comment: @WanderingMind `sed '/SMEAR/d;$a\SMEAR=-5` would be something like this `ex` method to which the (unportable) `-i` option could be included.

Comment: @thrig - that would fail if the last line matched though...

Comment: @WanderingMind, that's a good question; I've updated my answer to describe the `ex` method for doing this.

Comment: I'm unable to pass a variable as a value in this command. Can you tell me how is this done

Comment: @WanderingMind, you mean for the new value of SMEAR, or for the name SMEAR itself?  (You didn't mention this in your original question....)

Comment: @Wildcard I meant pass value of SMEAR as a variable. I have added an EDIT to the question

Comment: @WanderingMind, including SMEAR as a variable is really a very different breed of fish, because it involves sanitizing the variable before you use it.  But if you don't care about the potential dangers or are sure that SMEAR can't be interpreted as other than a literal string (and doesn't contain e.g. any slashes or meta-characters), you can just change `'g/SMEAR/d'` to `"g/$myvar/d"` in any of the given `ex` commands.

Comment: Oh, I see—the value.  That's much safer; replace `'SMEAR=-5'` with `"SMEAR=$myvar"`.  (It's much safer because it is within the `ex` instruction to append literal text, so unless there is a *very* crafty malicious user it won't do anything unintended.)  (The malicious user setting this variable *could* have it do something else, though; e.g. don't try it with `myvar=$'\n.\n%d\nx'`.

Answer (score 5):

You could try like this: if a line matches just copy it to the `h`old space then `s`ubstitute the value.
On the la`$`t line e`x`change hold space and pattern space then check if the latter is empty. If it's not empty, it means the substitution was already made so nothing to do. If it's empty, that means no match was found so replace the pattern space with `SMEAR=-5` then append to the current line in the hold buffer. Finally, e`x`change again:

```
sed '/SMEAR/{h;s/.*/SMEAR=-5/};${x;/^$/{s//SMEAR=-5/;H};x}' infile
```

The above is `gnu sed` syntax. Portable:

```
sed '/SMEAR/{
h
s/.*/SMEAR=-5/
}
${
x
/^$/{
s//SMEAR=-5/
H
}
x
}' infile
```

Alternate way with `ed`:

```
ed -s infile<<\IN || printf %s\\n SMEAR=-5 >> infile
/SMEAR.*/s//SMEAR=-5/ 
w
q
IN
```

If no line matches pattern, `ed` will error out so the second command (`printf...`) will be executed to append the line to the file. Otherwise `ed` will edit the file in-place.

---

If you have the value of `SMEAR` saved in variable e.g.

```
var=-7
```

you would run:

```
sed '/SMEAR/{h;s/.*/SMEAR='"$var"'/};${x;/^$/{s//SMEAR='"$var"'/;H};x}' infile
```

or

```
ed -s infile<<IN || printf %s\\n "SMEAR=${var}" >> infile
/SMEAR.*/s//SMEAR=${var}/ 
w
q
IN
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me is there a way to pass the value of SMEAR as a variable.  If I use `$var` and `" "` in above command, `sed` complains saying `bad substitution`

Answer (score 1):

Or, implementing [Wildcard’s idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282605/80216#282607)
(remove any/all existing line(s) that contain `SMEAR`,
and then insert the line you want) with stone-age tools:

```
(grep -v '^SMEAR=' file1; echo 'SMEAR=-5') > file1.tmp  &&  cp file1.tmp file1  &&  rm file1.tmp
```

or, if you aren’t concerned
about preserving the attributes (e.g., permissions) of
and hard links to `file1`, you could do

```
(grep -v '^SMEAR=' file1; echo 'SMEAR=-5') > file1.tmp  &&  mv file1.tmp file1
```

or, if you have `sponge`, you could do

```
(grep -v '^SMEAR=' file1; echo 'SMEAR=-5') | sponge file1
```

Comment: This will probably be much faster when used with `-F` and dealing with huge input files...

Comment: Yeah, but, while the OP talks about a line containing the string `SMEAR`, I suspect that they would not want to lose a line that said `FOO=BAR_SMEAR_BAZ` or even `BESMEARED=42`. I believe that any solution that doesn’t anchor `SMEAR` to the beginning of the line and require that it be immediately followed by an `=` is flawed, and has the risk of behaving in ways that the OP doesn’t want.